# Is it possible to code this formula using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to code the following formula using recursion. 
[image]
I was thinking of doing it in different ways, but since the expression is recursive, in my opinion recursion is the way to go.
I know how to apply recursion to simple problems, but in this particular case my understanding seems to be wrong. I tried to code it in python, but the code failed with the message

```
 RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Therefore, I would like to ask what is the best way to code this expression and whether recursion is possible at all.

The python code I tried is:

```
def coeff(l,m,m0,m1):
  if l==0 and m==0:
    return 1.
  elif l==1 and m==0:
    return -(m1+m0)/(m1-m0)
  elif l==1 and m==1 :
    return 1./(m1-m0)
  elif m<0 or m>l:
    return 0.
  else:
    return -((l+1.)*(m1-m0))/((2.*l+1.)*(m1+m0))* \
    ((2.*l+1.)*(m+1.)/((l+1.)*(2.*m+3.)*(m1-m0))*coeff(l,m+1,m0,m1) +\
       (2.*l+1.)*m/((l+1.)*(2.*m-1.)*(m1-m0))*coeff(l,m-1,m0,m1) -\
       l/(l+1.)*coeff(l-1,m,m0,m1))
```

where `x=m1-m0` and `y=m1+m0`. In my code I tried to express the `a(l,m)` coefficient as a function of the others and code the recursion on the basis of it.

Comment: Dynamic programming is probably better suited for this.

Comment: I would avoid recursion every time i could. DP seems a mush better and faster solution

Comment: How do you call coeff(...)? Also, what does "rin" mean?

Comment: @Ukimiku I would call it by using something like `coeff(1,2,-0.8,1.)`.

Comment: @GáborErdős ok, so you are basically suggesting to code this using a loop.

Comment: The formula you propose leads to an infinite sequence for any m > 1. And in either way, the recursive depth of such formulas shouldn't be underestimated. I'd recommend a DP-approach to improve the performance and double-checking the definition of your formula.

Comment: @Paul the formula comes form a paper. I just copied it. I was also thinking that the `a(l,m+1)` might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A naive recursive implementation here, obviously recalculates the same things over and over. It probably pays to store things previously calculated. This can be done either by explicitly filling out a table, or implicitly by memoization (I therefore don't really agree with the comments taking about "recursion vs. dynamic programming").

E.g., using [this decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize),

```
class memoize(dict):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self[args]

    def __missing__(self, key):
        result = self[key] = self.func(*key)
        return result
```

You could write it as

```
@memoize
def calc_a(l, m, x, y):
    if l == 0 and m == 0:
        return 1
    # Rest of formula goes here.
```

Note that the same link contains a version that caches between invocations.

There are a number of tradeoffs between (memoized) recursion and explicit table building:

1. Recursion is typically more limited in the number of invocations (which might or might not be an issue in your case - you seem to have an infinite recursion problem in your original code).
2. Memoized recursion is (arguably) simpler to implement than explicit table building with a loop.

Comment: thank you for reply, but unfortunately I still get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: @AlexanderCska Does your `coeff` call `coeff` or `rin`?

Comment: It calls `coeff`, the other name is just a mistake. Otherwise it would not be a recursion. Thank you for pointing that out, I corrected the mistake. Anyway I think that the formula is wrong. Because it asks for `a(l,m+1)` and we don't have any `m+1` terms.

Comment: @AlexanderCska That is exactly the infinite recursion (just didn't notice it in the formula). Mathematically, this is ill defined; the code manifestation is an infinite recursion. When you find the right formula, I suggest you still use memoization if the formula has overlapping sub-problems.

Comment: just to get the idea correct, how should i modify the formula to make the recursion work.

Comment: @AlexanderCska It doesn't quite go like that. The formula needs to be derived from something. This one has indications that there is a mistake in the derivation, but I can't tell what. In particular, if a_m depends on a_{m - 1} (I'm just focussing on m for now), then there must be stopping conditions for some starting values of m (e.g., 0, 1). Similarly, if a_m depends on a_{m + 1}, then there must be stopping conditions for some terminating values of m, and there simply aren't here any.

Comment: I was missing a condition, namely `elif m<0 or m>l:
    return 0.`. But still the code does not work

Comment: @AlexanderCska Can you verify that your question contains the most up to date code? When it's so, feel free to ping here, in a comment.

Comment: actually I posted the solution. If you would put `m0=0` and `m1=1`, it is possible to test the formula. I don't really understand why the decorator is needed. I was able to run it without it.